# populate combo box in installshield using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, windows-installer, installshield

I am trying to populate a combo box in Installshield with a list of network adapter names on the local machine. I'm trying to use a vbscript custom action which I modified a bit from here : http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?t=188130

```
MsiRecord.StringData(1) = "REGION" 'The Name of the Property
```

I seem to be getting an error on this line, and the installation crashes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your talking about updating windows installer tables using VBScript custom actions this really has everything to do with Windows Installer and not much to do with InstallShield per say.

I don't think that example posted on the forums was correct.  I'd suggest reading the following page to get a better understand and take a look at the Combobox and ListBox sample projects provided.

[Using Dual ListBoxes as Replacement for a Multi-Selection ListBox](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/articles/MultiListBox/index.htm)

Personally I suspect the problem with the sample you quoted is missing a Set statement when creating the record.  As I recall, and it's been awhile since I touched VBScript,  you have to use the Set command when creating an object.   But I really advise against using VBScript in Custom Actions.  C/C++, InstallScript and C# ( using DTF ) are far more robust solutions.

Comment: I have tried using both Set and Dim when creating the record an neither worked.  Also I'm not sure why you linked with that page as it is a reference to Advanced Installer which I am not using at all.

Comment: I linked it because Advanced Installer and InstallShield are both using Windows Installer as their underlying technology.  Thus the included VBScript CustomAction sample works with InstallShield.

Comment: Actually, nevermind.  Now that I look at their sample more closely they are punting the interesting parts to another custom action contained in a file called aicustact.dll.  Let me try to find your another sample.  I know Stefan Krueger has one called Ice Cream but I haven't been able to find it  yet.